# SQL Error Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: c#, sql, parameterized-query

```
        private void FillInvoiceList()
    {
        DataTable distinctInvoice = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["APOS_CONNECTION_STRING"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select distinct svc_tag from data where rep_name = @value");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", this.DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, conn.ConnectionString);
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(distinctInvoice);
        }
        foreach (DataRow row in distinctInvoice.Rows)
        {
            this.ListBox1.Items.Add(row["svc_tag_dim_invoice_num"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

I have this code and I get this error when I call the Fill(DistinctInvoice)

Must declare the scalar variable "@value"

My FillInvoiceList() Method is being called from a SelectedIndexChanged event from the DropDownList1.  The value of DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text seems to be correct.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is here :

```
SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, conn.ConnectionString);
```

You're setting the SQLDataAdapter to use the original CommandText, not the SQLCommand itself. Change it to :

```
SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn.ConnectionString);
```

Comment: It doesn't look like SqlDataAdapter() isn't overloaded to take a cmd and connection object.   I'm adding the connection to the SqlCommand constructor

Comment: You, sir, are a hero. I've wasted the half past hour googleing around and no one seemed to get it right. Then your answer popped up. Thanks!